# Does firewall count as a subnetwork?

Tags: firewalls, ip

I need to design a network based on IP 10.1.1.0/24. I have three different subnetworks and a firewall. Does firewall count as a subnetwork? Do I need to assign some IP values to it?

Comment: Routed or transparent firewall?

Comment: Closed - this is basic networking, not information security.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, firewall is not subnetwork. The only point is firewall should have on one (or more than one) network interface IP from each subnet. Otherwise will be not possible to serve those subnets
For example if you have networks:

- 10.1.1.0/25
- 10.1.1.128/26
- 10.1.1.192/26

you should assign to firewall (for example)
10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.129 and 10.1.1.192

Comment: So, the firewall is not a subnetwork but it should have an ip that belongs to all subnetworks then? How can I create such an IP address? Subnetwork's IP addresses are different from each other.

Comment: no, you should have one IP from each subnet. Check my edited answer

Comment: Depends if routed or transparent.  Need more details.

Comment: @user1801810, based on the answer of OP can you guess what kind is?

Comment: Yes except for OP had not yet accepted the answer when I commented.  Answer accepted, question closed put on hold.